# How can I load data from JSON Object... not JSON Array

Tags: json, ag-grid

I'm using this standard code from the tutorial examples:

```
  agGrid
    .simpleHttpRequest({
      url: 'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json',
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
    });
```

But the JSON data I want to use is returned as an Object, not an array.
Like this:

```
{
"response": [
{"athlete":"Michael Phelps","age":23,"country":"United States","year":2008,"date":"24/08/2008","sport":"Swimming","gold":8,"silver":0,"bronze":0,"total":8},
{"athlete":"Michael Phelps","age":19,"country":"United States","year":2004,"date":"29/08/2004","sport":"Swimming","gold":6,"silver":0,"bronze":2,"total":8}
]
}
```

Their example files are arrays and start with a [

I can't seem to find any setRowData documentation to see if there's a way around this.
Any ideas?
thx

Answer (score 0):

you'll get the array from data replacing **data** with **data.response** :

```
agGrid
.simpleHttpRequest({
  url: 'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json',
})
.then(function (data) {
  gridOptions.api.setRowData(data.response);
});
```

Best !